# Mark emails manually in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I wonder whether there is any option in Lotus Notes (8.5) to manually mark an email - preferentially by color - in the main email view.

I would like to do something like: Right-click, change complete email header to red (that would be the best case).
I do not want to setup general filters. I want to use this for a workflow like "I want to remember this particular email, something has to be done there". Or "I want to remember this particular email, there is an important information inside".

At the moment I solve this by copying mails to specific folders, but adding colors or tags (e.g.) to them would make it much easier to find things again. It would enable me to scroll through the mails quickly and just hold when there is something in red, blue or purple -> whatever.

Do you have any suggestions how to achieve this?

Btw - in MS Outlook I liked the "Category" feature. That would fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes has follow up flags, you generally can right click to 'quick flag' them which moves them from the inbox to the follow up view.  You can also click the flag toolbar button and create your own flags or flag them as high priority.  Using the toolbar button leaves them in the inbox but also displays them in the follow view and the follow up mini view in the lower left hand corner of your Notes client.

[This link has more info](https://qp.research.ibm.com/help/help8_client.nsf/2e73cbb2141acefa85256b8700688cea/15b7ea9ab90546bd852576090012146b?OpenDocument)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already found out about the flag option and use it from time to time. I would actually prefer something a bit more flexible - e.g. create own flags, not being forced to "urgent", "normal", "low". But it seems Lotus Notes does not offer this kind of flexibility.

Comment: TBH, it's probably beyond what you want to do, but you can customize anything you want using lotusscript, assuming your server admins don't have it locked down.  You do know about sender colors right?  That may help some if the emails you'd like to sort have the same senders.